# filter the data when retrieving from json JSONArray

Tags: android, json, filter

I have implemented a swipeable tabs using (http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/). I have a grid in my 1st tab which is a fragment. I am getting a json response carrying the items to load in the 1st tab. at the moment i have loaded all the items. but these items belongs to 3 categories. So i have a footer as shown in the image to filter the items as needed. at the moment i have 28 items belongs to all these 3 categories. Currently im loading all the items. i want to change when i pressed 1st footer it should filter and show only the items belong to that. I need some advice how to do it?
any help would be appreciated.

[image]

pizzaFragment is the 1st tab and in footer of that page i hav 3 textviews to filter the items

pizzafragment

```
public class PizzaFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {

    private QuickReturnListView mListView;
    private TextView mQuickReturnViewTop;
    private TextView mQuickReturnViewBig;
    private TextView mQuickReturnViewIta;

    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main_pizza, container, false);

        new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();

        mQuickReturnViewTop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footerTop);
        mQuickReturnViewBig = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footerBig);
        mQuickReturnViewIta = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footerIta);

        mQuickReturnViewTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //change last selected view to be normal
                if(selectedView != null)
                     selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8000000"));

                //set selectedView to be current selected view
                selectedView = (TextView)v;

                //change selected view to be red
                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e92624"));



                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "toppings!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        mQuickReturnViewBig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedView != null)
                     selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8000000"));

                //set selectedView to be current selected view
                selectedView = (TextView)v;

                //change selected view to be red
                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e92624"));



                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "big!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        mQuickReturnViewIta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedView != null)
                     selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8000000"));

                //set selectedView to be current selected view
                selectedView = (TextView)v;

                //change selected view to be red
                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e92624"));



                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ita!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_pizza);
        return view;


}
    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("2")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("8")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                }

            }

            CustomGridPizza adapter = new CustomGridPizza(getActivity(), descriptions,
                    imageUrls, price);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eaeaea"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MenuItems" >


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_pizza"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="7dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="7dp" />

    <lk.gamma.pizzakraft.menu.QuickReturnListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerBig"
        android:layout_width="106.5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:text="@string/footer3"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
    <!-- android:background="#D8000000" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerIta"
        android:layout_width="107dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/footerTop"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
        android:text="@string/footer2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerTop"
        android:layout_width="106dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
        android:text="@string/footer1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show some related code

Comment: is toppings, italiano, big pizza are footer in single fragment or they are tabs?

Comment: @ Chitrang is toppings, italiano, big pizza are footer in single fragment. im using it as Quick Return Hide Footer, similar to facebook